# Small images change large image

Tags: html, jquery

So I have set up a product display area on my upcoming website, and I am attempting to have it so when you click on one of the smaller images, it changes the large image.

I have a specific layout of the HTML that I am going to require, so it is more now down to the jQuery.

```html
<ul class="image_list product-images">
   <li data-image="img/jonathan-benainous-front-shot-red-devil-portrait-3d-artist.jpg" class="image-clicker">
      <img src="img/jonathan-benainous-front-shot-red-devil-portrait-3d-artist.jpg" alt="Test Product">
   </li>
   <li data-image="img/maze-solved.png" class="image-clicker">
      <img src="img/maze-solved.png" alt="Test Product">
   </li>
   <li data-image="img/maze.png" class="image-clicker">
      <img src="img/maze.png" alt="Test Product">
   </li>
   <li data-image="img/jonathan-benainous-front-shot-grey-portrait-3d-artist-watermark.jpg" class="image-clicker">
      <img src="img/jonathan-benainous-front-shot-grey-portrait-3d-artist-watermark.jpg" alt="Test Product">
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="image_selected">
   <img class="main-img" src="img/jonathan-benainous-front-shot-red-devil-portrait-3d-artist.jpg" alt="Test Product">
</div>
```

The jQuery I have currently (that isn't working) is:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready({
        $('.image-clicker').on({
            'click': function(){
                $('main-img').attr('src', this.val('data-image'));
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

If anyone can assist me in this, that would be great!

Comment: please tell what "doesn't work", do you have an error in the 'console' dev panel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You are not calling the right selector.
change `'main-img'` to `'.main-img'`.

You can also call a data attribute value using this:
`$('.element').data('foo')` or `$('.element').attr('data-foo')` the first one being preferred.

```
<script>
    // shorthand for document ready
    $(function(){
        $('.image-clicker').on('click', function(){
            var src = $(this).data('image')
            $('.main-img').attr('src', src)
        })
    })
</script>
```